# Issue with Inner and Left Join

Tags: join

I am writing a Query that combines columns from two different tables. I am currently reading data from a CSV file and doing data reconcilliation. The fields are as follows
Let us call both tables Creditors and Takers. The creditors DB has the credit name, the Trade_Acct_Number, two distinct identifiers called trade_ID and action_ID. The takers table on the other hand has a corresponding Trading_Account_Num and it's two distinct identifiers trade_ID and action_ID.

Here are the conditions; the records are to be matched primarily on the Trading_Acct_Numbers. Then based on the trading_Account_Num we further filter the data based on the trade_ID and action_ID. Trade_ID's are 8 characters long; If there is a match on the last 6 characters of the trade_ID then we reflect that data; else we check the action_ID.

Here is my current query (Written in SQL Server CE)

```
SELECT
CR.CREDIT_NAME,
TK.TRADE_ACCT_NUM,
CR.CREDIT_REG_NUM,
TK.TRADE_ID,
TK.ACTION_ID

FROM [TAKER] TR
INNER JOIN [CREDITOR] CR
ON TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM = CR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM
WHERE SUBSTRING([TRADE_ID],3,8) = SUBSTRING([TRADE_ID],3,8)
OR TR.ACTION_ID = CR.ACTION_ID

ORDER BT
TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM
```

Currently with my table I have the following issues. I get about 90% of my desired output for matches however some rows from the Takers table are omitted totally. Sometimes there is a match based on Account number but the TRADE_ID is null with an Action_ID which causes the row to not be outputted. There are also no outputs for when there is a match on both the Trade_Acct_Num and the Action_ID but not the Trade_ID. I tried doing a left join followed by an inner join but it did not help my situation. Please help and explain. Thanks

Comment: Your example is missing CR. and TR. on the substring check.
Can you post an example of the data that you think should come up but does not?

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to try:
alter table [TAKER] add TRADE_MATCH AS SUBSTRING ([TRADE_ID],3,6) to create a pseudo-field to which you can then add an index to speed up this query.

Answer (score 1):

A LEFT join will just provide null values for all your creditor fields.  You just need to allow for the possibility of nulls in your trade_id or your credit_id in the joined creditors table.  As Mike mentioned above, some example data would be helpful.

```
SELECT
CR.CREDIT_NAME,
TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM,
CR.CREDIT_REG_NUM,
TR.TRADE_ID,
TR.ACTION_ID

FROM [TAKER] TR
INNER JOIN [CREDITOR] CR
ON TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM = CR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM
WHERE SUBSTRING(TR.TRADE_ID,3,8) = CASE WHEN CR.TRADE_ID is null 
      then SUBSTRING(TR.TRADE_ID,3,8) ELSE SUBSTRING(CR.TRADE_ID,3,8) END
OR TR.ACTION_ID = CASE WHEN CR.ACTION_ID is null 
      then TR.ACTION_ID else CR.ACTION_ID end
ORDER BT
TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM
```

This is just checking to the cr.trade_id is null and if so, return the tr.trade_id so it will evaluate to true and then go on to test the credit_id in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

@Victor, I thought of another possibility depending on your date.  If the trade_id from both tables is null, you must test for both being null because null does not equal null.  I hope one of the answers does what you need.

```
SELECT
CR.CREDIT_NAME,
TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM,
CR.CREDIT_REG_NUM,
TR.TRADE_ID,
TR.ACTION_ID

FROM [TAKER] TR
INNER JOIN [CREDITOR] CR
ON TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM = CR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM AND
    (  SUBSTRING(TR.TRADE_ID,3,8) = SUBSTRING(CR.TRADE_ID,3,8)
    OR (TR.TRADE_ID is null and CR.TRADE_ID is null)
    OR TR.ACTION_ID = CR.ACTION_ID
    OR (TR.ACTION_ID is null and CR.ACTION_ID is null)
    )
ORDER TR.TRADE_ACCT_NUM
```